# A normal subgroup of size 4 the group of rotational symmetries of a cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, symmetry

An exam question has asked me to show that there is a normal subgroup of size 4 of the group of rotational symmetries of the cube.

A trick I've seen before is considering the action of a group on its set of left cosets, but I don't think it works here.

Comment: What do you know about the full group? How large would the factor group be? Can you think of something suitable To act on. (hint: you want something that gives you an action of degreee 3. Can you find a structure in the cube that occurs exactly three times?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment I'll try to think about that... A structure that occurs exactly three times is pairs of opposite faces...

Comment: Yes. So what happens if you act on the pairs of faces (or the lines connecting two opposite faces)? How large will the image group be (it will be a subgroup or S3)

Comment: We have the kernel of the induced homomorphism $\phi$ from that action being a normal subgroup of G (the rotational symmetries group), and by the first isomorphism theorem $G$ \ $\text{Ker} \phi \cong \text{Im}\phi$, which is a subgroup of the symmetric group of pairs of faces, which has order 3!=6, so the kernel can't be trivial as G has size 24, so we've confirmed there's a subgroup of size 3 or 6?

Comment: Almost. The kernel has order 24/6.

Comment: Whoops, I think I pulled those numbers out of nowhere. But isn't $\text{Im} \phi$ just a subgroup of $S_3$? So why couldn't the image be size 3, thus making the kernel size 8?

Comment: Can you find elements in the image (from operations on the cube) that will have order 2, respectively 3?

Comment: Ah I see now, $\text{ord} \phi (g)$ divides $\text{ord} g$, so I need only find elements of G which have order 2 and 3. Such as the rotation that swaps a pair of faces but keeps the other two the same, and the rotation which maps pair 1 to pair 2, pair 2 to pair 3 and pair 3 to pair 1. And then we're done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could follow the individual steps but I think I lack the big picture creativity to do some group questions at the moment... I'll keep trying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to piece together all the pieces that ahulpke gave me (thanks) into a single answer.

Let $G$ be the group of rotational symmetries of a cube. Then consider the action of $G$ on the pairs of opposite faces of the cube, $X$. This action induces a homomorphism $$\phi:G \rightarrow \text{Sym}(X)$$ for which $\text{ker} \phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $$G/\text{Ker}\phi \cong \text{Im}\phi<\text{Sym}(X),$$and by observing that $\text{Im}\phi$ has an element of order 2 and 3 by considering certain rotations, we can conclude that $\text{Im}\phi$ must have size six as it is a subgroup of $\text{Sym}(X) \cong S_3$ which has six elements. As $G$ has 24 elements, $\text{Ker}\phi$ has $24/6=4$ elements, and we're done.

Comment: +1 for using this site as intended: to learn, not just to have your questions answered. Don't forget to accept your self-answer.